# Why don't background colour of some of textfields in my code change?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I am doing Sudoku project with a GUI. I have a two dimensional array to hold digits in 9x9 grids. I want to change background color of textfields that holds the value of the array that are not 0's. Here is a part of my code where I manipulate the textfields and a picture of the GUI. For example in first 3x3 grid, 5,4 and 1 digits background grey but 9 is not. What is the problem? Please help. Thank you.

```
public class Controller {
    private Board board;
    private TextField[] tfs;

    @FXML GridPane gridPane;
    @FXML Button startButton;
    @FXML Button stopButton;
    @FXML Label timeLabel;

    private final IntegerProperty timeSeconds = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    private Timeline timeline;

    public void initialize() throws IOException {
        board = new Board();
        tfs = new TextField[81];
        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                tfs[c] = new TextField();
                tfs[c].setFont(new Font(24));
                tfs[c].setPrefWidth(50);
                tfs[c].setPrefHeight(50);
                tfs[c].setText(board.getValue(i, j) + "");
                tfs[c].setDisable(true);

                if (board.getValue(i, j) != 0)
                    tfs[c].setStyle("-fx-background-color: #ebe6e6");

                if (i == 2 || i == 5)
                    tfs[c].setStyle("-fx-border-width: 1 1 3 1;");

                if (j == 2 || j == 5)
                    tfs[c].setStyle("-fx-border-width: 1 3 1 1;");

                if ((i == 2 || i == 5) && (j == 2 || j == 5))
                    tfs[c].setStyle("-fx-border-width: 1 3 3 1;");

                gridPane.add(tfs[c], j, i);
                int finalI = i;
                int finalJ = j;
                tfs[c].textProperty().addListener((bean_p, old_p, new_p) -> {
                    if (newValue.matches("[0-9]")) {
                        int a = Integer.parseInt(newValue);
                        boolean b = board.setValue(finalI, finalJ, a);
                        if (!b)
                            showAlert("Error", "Not a valid move.", Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
                    } else
                        showAlert("Error", "Invalid input.", Alert.AlertType.ERROR);

                    if (board.isGameFinished() && board.isBoardCorrect())
                        showAlert("Solved", "Congratulations. You solved the sudoku.", Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
                });

                c++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onPressedStartButton() {
        stopButton.setDisable(false);
        activateTextFields();
        startButton.setDisable(true); // prevent starting multiple times
        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), evt -> updateTime()));
        timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE); // repeat over and over again
        if (timeSeconds.get() != 0) {
        }
        timeline.play();
    }

    private void updateTime() {
        int seconds = timeSeconds.get();
        timeSeconds.set(seconds + 1);
        timeLabel.setText("Elapsed Time:   " + timeSeconds.get() + " sn");
    }

    public void onPressedStopButton() {
        if (timeline != null) {
            timeline.stop();
        }
        passivateTextFields();
        startButton.setDisable(false);
        stopButton.setDisable(true);
    }

    public void onPressedResetButton() {
        timeSeconds.set(0);
        timeLabel.setText("Elapsed Time:    0 sn");
    }

    public void activateTextFields() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
            if (tfs[i].getText().equals("0"))
                tfs[i].setDisable(false);
        }
    }

    public void passivateTextFields() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
            if (tfs[i].getText().equals("0"))
                tfs[i].setDisable(true);
        }
    }

    public void showAlert(String title, String message, Alert.AlertType alertType) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(alertType);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setHeaderText(message);
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mcve] and some more information. which textfields do not change? is there a pattern in which they don't change? and post your complete code

Comment: I added complete code. I mentioned about which textfield don't change. I want to paint to grey background color of textfields that hold not 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your code I am assuming that you're using the TextField from `javafx.scene.control.TextField`. If you look at the image you attached the rows and columns that are not greyed out when they should are the 3rd and 6th row/column (index 2 and 5). The background style is overridden by the set border-widths.

Try this:

```
String style = "";
if (board.getValue(i, j) != 0) {
    style += "-fx-background-color: #ebe6e6;";
}

if ((i == 2 || i == 5) && (j == 2 || j == 5)) {
    style += "-fx-border-width: 1 3 3 1;";
} else if (i == 2 || i == 5) {
    style += "-fx-border-width: 1 3 1 1;";
} else if (j == 2 || j == 5) {
    style += "-fx-border-width: 1 3 1 1;";
}
tfs[c].setStyle(style);
```